# How to add a folder on Shinyio to upload multiple files

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have close to 30 files with different names to upload. I was looking to choose a local data path which then can be used to upload the many files.

I have added a very simplified version of my code so I do not confuse people. This is using `library(shinyFiles)`, specifically `shinyDirButton` in the ui and `shinyDirChoose` in the server.

This is running locally on R Studio, but when I add it to my **shinyio app**, I am unable to get the local folders to show up on my app.

Is there a solution? I tried `fileInput`, but it does not seem to be working either.

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  mainPanel("Hydro-BID-Opt",
            tabsetPanel(
              tabPanel("Information required for the model",
                       numericInput("Res", label = h3("Total Res"), 
                                    min = 1, max = 25, 
                                    value = 3),
                       numericInput("Muns", label = h3("Total Users"), 
                                    min = 1, max = 150, 
                                    value = 5),
                        numericInput("Time", label = h3("Total Number of Months"), 
                                    min = 0, max = 60, 
                                    value = 12)
              ),
              tabPanel("Adding the folder",
                       shinyDirButton("directory", "Please add your data path where the csv files are stored", "Please select a folder", FALSE)
              ),
              tabPanel("Results", 
                       h3("Results for Cost"),
                       textOutput("Table_Cost")
              )
              )))


server<-function(input, output, session) {
  Mo <- reactive({input$Time})
  R <- reactive({input$Res})
  Mu <- reactive({input$Muns})

  volumes <- getVolumes()
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory', roots=volumes, session=session)
  path1 <- reactive({
    return(print(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)))
  })

  ## ResMax
  Resmaxcsv <- eventReactive(input$directory, {
    datpath_two <- paste0(path1(),"/MRC.csv")
    dataruw_Resmaxcsv <- read.csv(datpath_two, check.names=F, header = T)
    dataruw_Resmaxcsv
  })


  ## Cost
  Costcsv <- eventReactive(input$directory, {
    datpath_seven <- paste0(path1(),"/Cost.csv")
    dataruw_Costcsv <- read.csv(datpath_seven, check.names=F, header = T)
    dataruw_Costcsv
  })

  #### Running the model
  Test <- reactive({
    nT<-Mo()
    nR<-R()
    nM<-Mu()

    ##  ResMax
    resmaxcapacity<-Resmaxcsv()
    SCmax_rt<-array(data = resmaxcapacity[,2] * 1e-6, dim = c(nR, nT))

    ## Cost
    costcsv<-Costcsv()
    cost<-as.matrix(costcsv[,2:(nM+1)])
    costQ <- array(data = cost[1:nR, 1:nM], dim = c( nR, nM, nT))

    App<-apply(costQ, MARGIN = c(1,3), mean)
    TOTAL<-SCmax_rt+App
    print(TOTAL)
  })


  output$Table_Cost<-renderPrint({Test()})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little late but I think I have figured out the solution to upload a folder into a shiny app. I have tested it on a chrome browser and it will work fine for Edge & Firefox as well.

You can check the demo here:

https://absuag.shinyapps.io/FileExplorer/

Upload a folder and it will print all the files selected in the main panel.

I have used HTMLInputElement.webkitdirectory to upload the folder. Here is the source code for the shiny app.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "yellow",
                    # Title
                    dashboardHeader(title = "File-Explorer",titleWidth=140,uiOutput("logoutbtn")),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      tags$button(HTML('<input id = "folderPath1" type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory /> 
                                                    <input id = "folderPath2" type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory />'))),
                    dashboardBody(
                                  textOutput("text1"),
                                  textOutput("text2"),
                                  tableOutput("table1")
                      )
)
server <- function(input,output){
    observeEvent(input$folderPath1,{
        output$text1 <- renderText({
                print(paste0(input$folderPath1$name,collapse=","))
        })
        output$table1 <- renderTable({
            df <- read.csv(input$folderPath1$datapath[1])
        })
})
  observeEvent(input$folderPath2,{
    output$text2 <- renderText({
      print(paste0(input$folderPath2$name,collapse=","))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```